# I am trying to implement a program recursively. I just don't understand why my last line is being executed twice

Tags: c++, recursion, factorial

Why is `Hi` being printed 4 times. It will just be executed once before the function finally returns the complete value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int k = 0;
int factorial (unsigned int i) {
  if (i <= 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    k = i * factorial(i - 1);
  }
  printf("hi"); // Why is Hi being printed 4 times. 
  return k;
}

int main() {
  int i = 5;
  printf("Factorial of %d is %d\n", i, factorial(i));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to step through your code using a debugger?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there's no reason to have `k` being a global variable. There's no reason to have a variable in the first place, just do `return i * factorial(i - 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printf`'s are probably getting queued as the function is trying to call itself.

Let's examine it iteration by iteration -

```
i = 5
```

Iteration 1:

```
k = 5 * factorial(4);
```

Iteration 2:

```
k = 4 * factorial(3);
```

Iteration 3:

```
k = 3 * factorial(2);
```

Iteration 4:

```
k = 2 * factorial(1);
```

At this point, `factorial(1)` actually returns 1. Note that `printf` line is not reached in case.

Now, this value is fed to `k` in iteration 4 and its returned back to its caller while doing a `printf`.

The same happens in iteration 3, it receives a value in `k` and returns it to its caller i.e. iteration 2 while doing another `printf`

Now, iteration 2 receives a value for `k` and returns it to its caller i.e. iteration 1 while doing yet another `printf` (3rd time!)

Finally, iteration 1 receives a value for `k` and returns it, and along with that it does a final `printf` (Total 4)

I hope that explains your issue!
For ref: http://ideone.com/VgIwKX

Answer (score 5):

Because your code gets executed in this fashion:

```
k = 5 * factorial(5 - 1);
    k = 4 * factorial(4 - 1);
        k = 3 * factorial(3 - 1);
            k = 2 * factorial(2 - 1);
               return 1;
            printf("hi"); 
        printf("hi"); 
    printf("hi"); 
printf("hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `factorial()` is called five times:

- the first time by the `main()` method and
- four times recursively.

All the times that the `i` parameter is `> 1` the function prints `"hi"`.
Even if you are using the recursion, the execution if a program (or function) ends when the end point is reached, for a function the end point is the `return` statement.